# 3d acceleration under kvm

Tags: unity, kvm-virtualization, 3d

Hey guys I'm new to kvm and virt-manager.
Recently I've been trying testing the new ubuntu 12.04 alpha 2 and found unity3d in a unacceptable speed.
After some googleing, I found it may be the kvm-opengl problem.

And since I'm using virt-manager to manage my guest ubuntu under host ubuntu 11.10 64bit,Is there any chance to get it work in a acceptable speed?

I see there is qxl\vga\vmvga\xen\cirrus options under the graphic driver selection preference, but qxl and xen is not working to boot up my os.

And it seems that vmgl is not working on 64bit os.
So I really don't get a clue how to do so.
Wish someone could help me out!

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately 3D hardware-acceleration is a no-go for KVM yet - it's something I'm eagerly awaiting myself.

Keep an eye on the Spice project:
http://spice-space.org/page/PlannedFeatures

Answer (score 3):

I've been keeping a keen eye on this for a log time now, but AFAIK development has stalled since the Gallium3D track was stalled: http://spice-space.org/page/Features/3D

To me, this is a key piece of technology missing from very innovative implementations, especially if it can harness addition PCIe GPU's on the host to help with the (pre-)render.

For myself, I would like to build something like my full Ubuntu Unity desktop, or a dedicated Steam gaming VM instance, and then use something like a fat thin-client, like the  Raspberry Pi, to access & display the IO on the host.

But without a strong 3D HA in VDi, this will remain a pipe-ream in FLOSS-land

Answer (score 1):

There's finally a glimmer of hope on the horizon: Virgil
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQxNDY

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.