# How do I run Ubuntu in headless mode?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, headless

I would like to set up Ubuntu in headless mode - configured to operate without a monitor, keyboard, and mouse; probably without access to graphics hardware altogether. The rationale for this is: I will have a KVM virtual machine running that would have graphics hardware to itself.

How do I do it? Which Ubuntu distribution could I be using and why? The options that come to my mind are *desktop* and *server*, but both don't offer an option to be installed in headless mode by default, or do they?

I am going to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x86_64 on a [ThinkPad X Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_X_Series) (intel integrated graphics).

Comment: Ubuntu server does that. You just need to install OpenSSH (if it is not already installed by default) to connect to it.

Comment: @Salem Sorry, I need more specific instructions than that. Also, I suppose, Ubuntu server would detect VGA and utilize it by default, too; I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect VGA"? You graphics card will always be detected by the kernel, but as Ubuntu server only has a CLI it would not be used...

Comment: @Salem If VGA wouldn't be used, I wouldn't see the text-mode installer on the screen and choose options during the installation. Also, after the installation, I wouldn't be able to log in and issue commands using the display of my laptop. Last time I tried installing Ubuntu server, that's how it worked when I installed it on my laptop. I presume that's because Ubuntu server installer detects the presence of VGA adapter and figures it can use it as a console. I need to use ssh as my only means of interaction;  probably don't let dom0 see the VGA at all, so that VM can have it all to itself.

Comment: Can you give an example of an OS that does what you need?

Comment: @Salem I presume most (if not all) Unix-like OS can do it; I just need to know how to use them, as it isn't the default way of doing things.

Comment: Do you have a serial port? If you do, Ubuntu Server should start a terminal on it by default. If you have ethernet, you can use [netconsole](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole). Once you have that working you should be able to disable the video by blacklisting or removing the `i915` kernel driver. The PCI port will still be detected and then you can forward it to the VM.

Comment: @bain ok, I'm reading about [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apbs01.html) and in the [example preconfiguration file](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apbs01.html) it says that "network-console component for remote installation over SSH" ... "only makes sense if you intend to perform the remainder of the installation manually." Why? I think it would make sense to 'preseed' the host OS installation, configured to be accessed over ssh, and go from there.

Comment: That is a network console for preseeding. What it means is that, if you have a preseed file, you can do a full automatic install, in which case you do not need a console. You can literally drop a CD into a PC, turn it on, wait for it to eject the PC, and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambigous. If you want to install ubuntu without any keyboard/monitor present, then you need to automate the installation. You'll generally find a lot of information about that if you look for "preseed" file and netinstallation. Please be aware that this may require some pre-existing infrastructure, depending on the exact method chosen (such as DHCP, TFTP services). You also want to do this with ubuntu server.

However please note that even KVM guests generally do have (virtualized) keyboard, mouse and monitor outputs and the KVM host on which the KVM guests run on generally have the ability to give you access to those via VNC connection. The end result is that you have a "headless" server but still console control over it remotely via VNC and you can perform the installation as if you had a monitor and keyboard on a real physical server.

Unless you really want to learn to automate an ubuntu server installation with no questions asked I strongly suggest investing time to see how you can get the console of KVM guests to appear whereever it is you are working from.

Comment: I intend to get the KVM guest's (but not the hosts') console to appear on my computer. Sorry if I didn't make this clear.